# iterate through values of each matrix in a list R

Tags: r, loops, matrix

Loop through each cell within each matrix in a list. My loop takes an nxn matrix and outputs a nx2 matrix of the co-ordinates of every non-NA value in the original matrix. I have succesfully written the code that achieves this for one matrix, how do I achieve this result for each matrix in a list. The output being a list of nx2 matrices.

I took one element of the list and looped through it succesfully, just struggling with appending my code to iterate through the list now

````
```r
m2=m1[[1]]
##ppp ready matrix

zzz <- NULL

for (i in 1:ncol(m2)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(m2)) {
    if (is.na(m2[i,j]) == FALSE){
    x=i
    y=j
    zzz <- rbind(zzz,c(i,j))

    }
  }
  }
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make your code into a function and use that function on your `m1` list.

```
matrixOperations <- function(m2) {
  zzz <- NULL

  for (i in 1:ncol(m2)) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(m2)) {
      if (is.na(m2[i, j]) == FALSE) {
        x <- i
        y <- j
        zzz <- rbind(zzz, c(i, j))
      }
    }
  }

  zzz
}

result <- lapply(m1, FUN = matrixOperations)
```

Comment: Thank you and how would I manipulate this code to include a third colum in the matrix that includes the values of the initial matrix at each set of co-ordinates?

Comment: Don't be afraid to ask a new (reproducible) question.

Answer (score 1):

I have a function that vectorizes these types of matrix operations by assigning row and column values to matrix indices (`sinkr::matrixIndex`).

The following example shows how it might work in your case:

#### Example

```
# make list of matrices (M) (I rows, J columns, K list levels)
I = 2
J = 5
K = 3

set.seed(1)
M <- lapply(split(seq(K), seq(K)), FUN = 
  function(k){matrix(sample(c(NaN,1), I*J, replace = TRUE), nrow = I, ncol = J)}
)


# return indices of non-NA values for each matrix (m) in list M
library(sinkr) # https://github.com/marchtaylor/sinkr

res <- lapply(M, FUN = function(m){
  matrixIndex(idx = which(!is.na(m)), dim.mat = dim(m))
})

# compare results
M[[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]  NaN  NaN    1  NaN    1
# [2,]    1  NaN  NaN  NaN    1

res[[1]]
# > res[[1]]
#      row col
# [1,]   2   1
# [2,]   1   3
# [3,]   1   5
# [4,]   2   5
```